# Need help understanding algorithm for longest consecutive item in array

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, logic

I'm given a vector which holds a binary value. I need to find the longest consecutive streak of 1's in the entire vector. This is the type of logic I can't quite solve. I can solve most cases, but not all, which means my algorithm is faulty. We can even change the manner of questions to ANY type of consecutive value in any array. I've tried a question counting Heads and Tails streaks, and still cannot solve 10/ 10 cases.

I think the algorithm gives a faulty answer when a streak begins at a later part of the vector instead of the largest streak starting at the first element.

Here is my algorithm for the problem requesting streaks based on binary values.
Also I understand 2 iterator values aren't the most efficient, but I want to simplify my answer in my terms.

SAMPLE INPUT:
[1,1,0]

SAMPLE OUTPUT:
2

SAMPLE INPUT 2: [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]

SAMPLE OUTPUT 2: 3

```
void getMaxStreaks(vector<int> arr) {
int largest_streak{0};
int streak_counter{0};

for(int i = 0; i <= arr.size() - 1; i++){
if(arr[i] == 1){
    streak_counter = 1;
}
    for(int j = i + 1; j <= arr.size() -1; j++){
        if(arr[i] == 1 && arr[j] == 1){
            streak_counter++;
        }

        else if(arr[i] == 1 && arr[j] == 0){
            if(streak_counter > largest_streak){
            largest_streak = streak_counter;
            streak_counter = 0;
            }
        }

    }
    if(streak_counter > largest_streak){
        largest_streak = streak_counter;
        streak_counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I'm given a vector which holds a binary value"_: this is very unclear. Do you mean you have a `vector<int>` containing only the values 0 and 1 ?

Comment: Also [edit] your question and show a [mcve]  including an example of input and expected vs. actual output

Comment: As you say the logic is completely wrong. A streak is **consecutive** values. Your code just tests individual values. Somewhere, somehow you need to test a vector value against it's predecessor.

Comment: I've added 2 different cases and correct outputs. Sorry for being unclear. And sorry, I meant to test WITHIN the vector of values. My brain might have fried from being stuck on this concept so apologies for lack of clarity.

Comment: Here's one way to do it. Your code needs to have boolean variable which is true if you are currently in a streak and false if not. Then when you read a 1, if you are not in a streak then you know you are starting one, and if you are in a streak you can increase the length of that streak by one. Then when you read a 0 and if you are in a streak then you know you have just finished one, so now you have the length of the just finished streak, which you can compare against the longest streak found so far.

Comment: Ahh I never thought of using booleans at all, I'll try this way! Thanks @john

Comment: Got it, I'll change it from there @molbdnilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bit of a long-winded answer. I'm sure you could simplify it even more, but all of the logic is here.

There are a number of things you were doing incorrectly:

1. Your array access started at 1, int i = 1, not 0, so you were skipping the first value in the array.
2. You can just write i < arr.size(), instead of i <= arr.size() - 1.
3. You were unnecessarily checking to see if the array was finished with i != arr.size() - 1, the for-loop will prevent this from ever happening.
4. You incremented streak_counter twice every time arr[i] == 1, because of the nested if-statement.
5. You set streak_counter to 0 every loop of the for-loop, preventing you from finding a streak more than 1.

```
void streak_checker(vector<int> arr)
{
    int streak_counter{ 0 };
    int largest_streak{ 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == 1)
        {
            streak_counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (streak_counter > largest_streak)
            {
                largest_streak = streak_counter;
            }
            streak_counter = 0;
        }
    }

    if (streak_counter > largest_streak)
    {
        largest_streak = streak_counter;
    }

    cout << largest_streak;
}
```

Comment: 1: I mixed 2 solutions up, one was a previous edit. I tried to take it on with one iterator variable as i - 1 will start the streak checker and i will be moving through the vector. Sorry for the mis-edit. I've been trying to tackle it for an hour... Thanks for checking on that error :)
4: Ahh I see why it was shooting over now! I approached it in an unorganized fashion.
5: Thanks for that catch! It was one of my ways to try to do the streak reset counter, but I see the error now. Thank you :)

Comment: @SKSam Glad I could help! I understand how ridiculous your code can get when trying to debug it! Also, just to explain the code a little bit: when the for loop is finished, if the final value was 1, then the streak_counter would be incremented, but the program would not check to see if it's larger than largest_streak. Therefore, there needs to be one more check to see if the current streak is larger. That's why there's 2 instances of the check. I believe this can be done better, but this is how I've always solved that problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The *algorithm* you're looking for is basically:

```
maxstart = 0, maxsize = 0                 # Initial maximum to date, zero
                                          # size means it'll be replaced by
                                          # any run of ones.
state = 0                                 # Initial state is "processing zeros",
                                          # meaning first one will start a run and
                                          # correctly initialise that run.

curr = 0                                  # For setting start of a run.
for each bit in bit_collection:           # Process every bit.
    if state == 0 and bit == 1:           # Catch transition zero -> one.
        start = curr, size = 1            # Initialise this run of ones.
        state = 1                         # Change state.
    elif state == 1:                      # Processing ones.
        if bit == 0:                      # Catch transition one -> zero.
            if size > maxsize:            # Replace longest if this one was longer.
                maxstart = start
                maxsize = size
        else:                             # Continuing a run of ones, increase size.
            size += 1
    curr += 1                             # Update index for run starts.

if state == 1:                            # Special handling of final run of ones.
    if size > maxsize:                    # Replace longest if this one is longer.
        maxstart = start
        maxsize = size
```

This is a state machine that ignores runs of 0's and counts runs of 1's. On any transition from `1` to `0` (including the "pretend" one at the end of the collection), we just check if the run just finished in longer the previously longest one and, if so, use this new run as the longest going forward.

At the end of this process, `maxstart` will hold the starting index of the largest run of ones, and `maxsize` will hold the count.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will read through it and integrate it to my own thinking :)